# Rails respond with protobuf / bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get my rails server to respond in proto.

When I do

```
bytes = item.to_proto
respond_with(bytes)
```

Rails says "Template is missing" and I've not found how to fix this. Which template should I use to just return raw bytes?

Answer (score 0):

respond_with is deprecated, try using:

```
render plain: bytes
```

or you can take a look on [`send_data`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data)

> This method is similar to render plain: data, but also allows you to
>   specify whether the browser should display the response as a file
>   attachment (i.e. in a download dialog) or as inline data